# Output Stem and Leaf Plot to Image

Tags: r, math

I'm trying to output a Stem and Leaf plot in R as an image. I'm not sure if there's a nice library which can accomplish this but below is some of the code I've tried.

```
jpeg(filename="stem.jpeg",width=480,height=480, units="px",pointsize=12)
plot.new()
tmp <- capture.output(stem(men, scale = 1, width = 40))
text( 0,1, paste(tmp, collapse='\n'), adj=c(0,1), family='mono' )
dev.off()
```

This above code resulted in the data being saved, but it looks very blurry and the plot gets cut off pretty badly. When adding a histogram to an image, R seems to do a good job to scale everything to fit in the size of the image.

```
jpeg(filename="stem.jpeg",width=480,height=480,
     units="px",pointsize=12)
stem(men, scale = 1, width = 40)
dev.off()
```

This created the image but had no content within it.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's because stem and leaf plots produce text not images. You can save the text as follows using the `sink` command: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sink.html

```
sink(file=“Stem.txt”)

stem(men, scale = 1, width = 40)

sink(file=NULL)
unlink("stem.txt")
```

Comment: So there's no way of saving that text into an image?

Comment: you can then just save the .txt as an image. i'm not aware of a way to save a stem plot as an image though.

Answer (score 0):

To export a stemplot as graphics, you can use a vector graphics format, such
as .eps, .pdf, or .emf. For example, a windows metafile:

```
win.metafile("stem.wmf", pointsize = 10)
plot.new()
tmp <- capture.output(stem(mtcars$mpg))
text(0,1,paste(tmp,collapse='\n'),family='mono',adj=c(0,1))
dev.off()
```